# How do you change DataGridView properties and values with threads in vb.NET?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview

I have been beating my head against the wall for 2 weeks now, while trying to figure out a way to navigate through the rows of the DataGridView component with threads. I want to do this, because if the gridview is more than 300+ rows long the UI will hang up for about 30-60 seconds.

I am new to multi-threading, but I do know now the importance of thread safe applications and having to make sure that changes to UI components are done on the UI thread.

The steps i want to take are as follows(Unless someone has a better suggestion):

1. User selects an item in a ListBox
2. Disable UI interaction from the user
3. The datagridview is broken up into searchable ranges
4. search through each range in parallel and hide any rows that match the items that are selected in the listbox.
5. resume UI interaction to the user

Ultimately I want to beable to select multiple items in the listbox to hide or show them.

What I am looking for is someone to give me some idea as to where to start? Should I go with background worker, Task Parallel Library, custom threads, ect...?

Comment: UI always works on one thread, called the UI thread. Heavy processing should be done on a separate thread. 300+ rows should not cause it to be slow. 30000 rows maybe.

Comment: Your code that is doing the hiding/showing is probably badly written. This doesn't sound like something that would require or benefit from multithreading. A blind guess: the DataGridView is probably being redrawn for each row you hide/show, instead of just once at the end.

Comment: @svinja - It does redraw each one as they hide aand show and I also intercept the OnPaint event which might also cause a slow down. Is there some way to prevent it from redrawing until all the rows have been hidden? I have tried the DataGridView.SuspendLayout() then call DataGridView.ResumeLayout() after I have hidden or shown the rows, but it doesn't prevent it from being drawn. And just for note so no one complains, DataGridView should be replaces with the variable name for the DataGridView component.